# ng-keydown not working on input field rendered through directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

In my `angular` view, I am using directive to render an `input field` and it works fine. But now I required to perform some action on `keydown`.

`ng-keydown` works fine with the input field I have in my view:

```
<input ng-keydown="tabed($event)" ng-model="myData2"/>
```

but it is not working with the input field which is rendered via directive

```
<my_input input-value="mydata"></my_input>
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('myInput', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<input ng-keydown="tabed($event)" ng-model="inputValue"/>',
    scope: {
        inputValue: '=',
        inputName: '='
    },
    link: function (scope) {

    }
  };
});
```

I have tried a lot but did not found any way to trigger `keydown` event on input field rendered via directive.

Here is the <kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkbharti/JJ5UM/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your directive created a new child scope, and in it's link function there is no tabed function. You can reference the parents scope via $parent. I highly recommend moving the tabed function to within the directive, but if you just need it this is the change you would need to make:

```
template: '<input ng-keydown="$parent.tabed($event)" ng-model="inputValue"/>',
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ5UM/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the same effects using `$watch` instead of `ng-keydown`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LN7d9/2/)

And here's how the directive should look;

```
app.directive('myInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<input ng-keydown="tabed($event)" ng-model="inputValue"/>',
        scope: {
            inputValue: '=',
            inputName: '='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.$watch('inputValue', function (now, then) {
                console.debug('yeah, I see the change', now, then);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I required to perform some action on tab key down so I need to know the key code. It is possible via your approach?

Comment: @user1690588 I think not, `$watch` only checks for value changes. I think in your case `ngKeydown` is the best way to go forward.